# How to set token holder's address without duplication?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, arrays

In following code I've implemented two functions to set and get Token holders.

```
 function setTokenHolders(address _to)internal returns(bool){
    for(uint i = 0; i<= tokenHolders.length; i++){
        if(_to != tokenHolders[i]){
            tokenHolders.push(_to);
            return true;
        }
        else{
            require(_to == tokenHolders[i],"Redundant token holder addresses.");
        }
    }
}
function getTokenHolders()public view returns(address[] memory){
    return tokenHolders;
}
```

My array's 0th element is initialized with my msg.sender. 
The logic of if is not worked as assumed.

Comment: Your `else` part doesn't do what you want it to do (you want to revert the transaction, but the `require` condition is always true instead of always false).

Comment: And the `<=` part inside the `for` loop is disastrous, because you always end up accessing the array at an illegal index (so the transaction will always revert).

Comment: okay, so what will I do?

Comment: And your logic in general won't work more than two times. For example, consider you've added "1", then "2", then "2" again. You need a `mapping` here, not an array!!!

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using mapping?

Comment: There is, but the running complexity will increase from `O(1)` to `O(n)`, and the gas cost will increase along with it (not to mention what will happen if you decide that you want to support removing values as well).

Answer (score 1):

Wow, your code and logic are full of errors!

First of all, with `for(uint i = 0; i<= tokenHolders.length; i++)`, you'll always end up attempting to access the array at an illegal index, so the transaction will **always** revert. To begin with, you need to change the `<=` to `<`.

Second, you are trying to maintain an array with unique values, but your logic of checking `_to != tokenHolders[i]` will generally not work more than twice. For example, consider the following sequence:

- After adding `0x1`, the array is `[0x1]`
- After adding `0x2`, the array is `[0x1, 0x2]`
- After adding `0x2`, the array is `[0x1, 0x2, 0x2]`, because `0x2 != tokenHolders[0]`

Third, your else part doesn't do what you want it to do (you want to revert the transaction, but the `require` condition is always `true` instead of always `false`).

Fourth, function `setTokenHolders` is declared to return a `bool` value, which I don't see why it needs to, since you apparently want it to succeed or revert (but never to fail silently). In any case, in its current implementation, you did not bother to return a value in all cases.

Fifth, as soon as the array becomes too long, you'll end up in a scenario where the transaction doesn't fit in a block (the gas required for executing it is larger than the block gas-limit). At this point, you will no longer be able to successfully execute the function (i.e., it will always revert due to exceeding block gas-limit).

In short, you need a `mapping` here, not an array:

```
mapping(address => bool) public tokenHolders;

function setTokenHolders(address _to) internal {
    require(tokenHolders[_to] == false);
    tokenHolders[_to] = true;
}
```